# getting an error code about using uninitialized memory

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am using visual studio to code with, and I do not understand why i am getting the error "Error C6001 - Using uninitialized memory '*tempPtr' " at only the line right below the else if condition statement.

```
void removeNumber(double*& arrayPtr, double number, int& size) {

    bool found = false;
    double* tempPtr = new double[size-1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        if (arrayPtr[i] == number) {
            found = true;

        }
        else if (found == false && arrayPtr[i] != number) {

            arrayPtr[i] = tempPtr[i];

        }
        else {

            arrayPtr[i] = tempPtr[i - 1];
        }

    } delete[] arrayPtr;
    arrayPtr = tempPtr;
    --size;
}
```

Comment: You're getting the error because, obviously, you're not initializing memory before you use it. Can you point out the exact line, above, that initializes any part of `tempPtr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 arrayPtr[i] = tempPtr[i];
```

In this line, you try to assign an uninitialized tempPtr[i] to an initialized arrayPtr[i]. It should be the other way around. However, if what you want to do is to assign a null pointer to arrayPtr[i], you can initialize tempPtr with null pointers.

This is not related to the question but I notice at the end you de-allocate the memory for arrayPtr and then use arrayPtr. This will crash your program at run-time. You only want to de-allocate when you have no use for it anymore.

Comment: The last paragraph is incorrect. After `arrayPtr` is deallocated, its pointer gets replaced by the newly-allocated `tempPtr`. This part appears to be correct, in the shown code.

Comment: Thanks for your input and answer. But you are right about the program crashing at the end. How could I clear the arrayPtr array and replace it with the contents of the tempPtr array in a better way?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I think arrayPtr doesn't get replaced by temPtr. Assigning arrayPtr to tempPtr means they now both point to the same memory address/ object. Hence you still need memory allocated for the arrayPtr.

Comment: Look again: `tempPtr`, which was allocated, is assigned to `arrayPtr` which was just `delete`d; and `arrayPtr` gets passed by reference.